# Remove ATT Apps

Tags: applications, att, bloatware

I just got a S3 from ATT and I see there's plenty of ATT apps I don't like. My friend recommended me other apps that are better that replace the ATT apps.

How can I remove these apps?

the unsinstall button is not available OR i see unsinstall updates.

thanks

Comment: I just added the 'bloatware' tag to your question (that's the term used for those pre-installed stuff not really needed), and updated the tag-wiki for it. What you most likely want to look for is tagged [freeze-app](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freeze-app); so meanwhile you might want to check the questions tagged such, or even better start with [that tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/freeze-app/info) to get started.

Comment: Please add some more info to your question: What Android version is your device running? Is it rooted?

Comment: what do you mean "is it rooted"?

Comment: See our [rooting tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info). Root is the "Superuser" aka "Administrator" account -- the one who has full control. This is disabled/not available by default on almost all devices. If you don't know, that answers this part (your device is obviously not rooted). Now you just need to tell the Android version running (go to *Settings->About phone* to find out).